# How can i create a function tag in my plugin

Tags: php, functions, conditional-tags

I want to know how what function or hook i can use  to create a php function that executes as tags  like this 
 `[block] content to be blocked[/block]` 
 my function will start with [start] afftected content goes here [/end]  anything inside the start tag and the end tag will be affected by my function, it could a simply unset or hide or exclude kind of function, please i need to include this in my plugin, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Enclosing Shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/). Here is an example of how you can achieve this.

```
function example_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    // do something to $content

    // run shortcode parser recursively
    $content = do_shortcode($content);

    // always return
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('example', 'example_shortcode');
```

Now you can use it like `[example] Here is my content [/example]`

Read more about `add_shortcode()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)

Comment: Thanks @Sabbir Hasan but where was the word example included in the code? Does it mean the code be used anyhow with anyword without a particular defined word to avoid conflicts. [example ] content here[/example]  this can also be [anyword] content goes here [/anyword[  won't this conflict?

Comment: See the very last line. `add_shortcode('example', 'example_shortcode');` **add_shortcode** accepts two parameter. First one is the `tag` and second is for the call back function.

Comment: I've added references for you. Please check.

Comment: I got it, thanks you have better explained it now